# Sql Server JOIN , MAX and GROUP BY

Tags: sql-server

I try to pull this one, and Im kinda stuck.

```
select 
distinct( msc.id),
 msc.campaignname ,
    max(mst.createdate) as mydate 
from MainMiniSiteCampaign as msc

right join MainMiniSiteTable as mst
on  mst.campaignid = msc.id

order by msc.id
group by msc.id
```

any ideas what Im doing wrong ?

(error is "incorrect syntax near the keyword 'group')

Comment: Remove `order by msc.id`

Comment: `order by` comes after `group by`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`GROUP BY` needs to be before `ORDER BY`

EDIT: I was't reading that far :)

Since you are grouping anyway, you don't need the `distinct` at all.

```
select 
msc.id,
 msc.campaignname ,
    max(mst.createdate) as mydate 
from MainMiniSiteCampaign as msc

right join MainMiniSiteTable as mst
on  mst.campaignid = msc.id

group by msc.id, msc.campaignname
```

And since a group by implies an order by in MySQL, you don't need to specifiy the `ORDER BY` neither. But you might want to add campaignname in the group by either, or else a random campaignname of each msc.id group will be picked. Or remove it from select when you don't need it.

Comment: I tried that, and if Im doing it, it says : Msg 8120, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Column 'MainMiniSiteCampaign.CampaignName' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.
Msg 145, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
ORDER BY items must appear in the select list if SELECT DISTINCT is specified.

Comment: @thormayer Edited my answer. Please have a look.

Answer (score 0):

first you shoud write group by then order by :

```
group by msc.id
order by msc.id
```

Answer (score 0):

Try like this ,

```
select 
distinct( msc.id),
msc.campaignname ,
max(mst.createdate) as mydate 
from MainMiniSiteCampaign as msc

right join MainMiniSiteTable as mst
on  mst.campaignid = msc.id

group by msc.id
order by msc.id
```

Comment: I tried that, and if Im doing it, it says : Msg 8120, Level 16, State 1, Line 1 Column 'MainMiniSiteCampaign.CampaignName' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause. Msg 145, Level 15, State 1, Line 1 ORDER BY items must appear in the select list if SELECT DISTINCT is specified.

Comment: the values of `msc.campaignname` are duplicated ? Can you show me some example with data ?

Comment: msc.campaignname are not duplicate in the msc table, the id is duplicate in the mst table

Answer (score 0):

```
select 
msc.id,
min( msc.campaignname) ,
max(mst.createdate) as mydate 

from MainMiniSiteCampaign as msc
right join MainMiniSiteTable as mst on  mst.campaignid = msc.id

group by msc.id
order by msc.id
```

You dont need `distinct(msc.id)` when using `group by msc.id`

Comment: `min( msc.campaignname) ` ? How did you decide to use `MIN`  ? But it may useful :)